# Figure Not Responding after returning to console from show()?

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib

At first, I wrote

```
## show the map and all that ##
def showMap():
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(im)
    # draw junctions as squares
    plt.scatter(junctionX, junctionY, marker='s', color='green')
    plt.show()
```

Then, the interactive console hangs until I close the figure. [This question gives a solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753885/pylab-matplotlib-show-waits-until-window-closes/9754238#9754238), and I modified my code to

```
## show the map and all that ##
def showMap():
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(im)
    # draw junctions as squares
    plt.scatter(junctionX, junctionY, marker='s', color='green')
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
```

Now, indeed I can return to the console and keep running other codes, **but my figure there becomes Non Responding**. How may I fix it?

---

I am using the [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/), because my project is a mix of a C++ project and a Python one. I have tested exactly the same code in Spyder, and it works perfectly fine there. So I think it is from the differences between IDEs.

Comment: How are you running this code?

Comment: What do you mean that the figure "becomes non responding"? Windows wants you to close the window? 

Also, what are you trying to do? If you want to just keep a matplotlib window open while you make another plot, then perhaps you can just just plt.show() and run each script in a new python interpreter (this is the default using IDLE, and I think there is a setting for it in Spyder somewhere). 

Alternatively, you can make multiple figures in matplotlib using "plt.figure()".

Comment: @tcaswell I sent the function snippet to interactive console. And then showMap().

Comment: what shell are you using?  I would suggest using `ipython` as that is what the interactive code was designed to work with.  I suspect the problem you have is that you don't have the correct thread-magic set up in the background.  (your using tk?)

Comment: @DanHickstein  By "becomes non responding", I mean the window hangs there unclickable, once you move the mouse on it, the mouse becomes a loading circle, just like any normal program while hanging. I need to see the plot changes as I update it in the interactive console. Since now it hangs, I won't see it updates

Comment: @tcaswell  Please see the updates in teh question

Comment: I know basically nothing about MS products, good luck!  Please add tags to make sure MS/visual studio types see this question.

Comment: @tcaswell  Thanks, but this actually has nothing to do with the MS VS, it is only a matter of a Python IDE

Comment: Unless I greatly miss-understood you, you are using an IDE embedded in/built on top of VS -> a MS VS problem.  You have to figure out how to replicate the threading magic/gui main loop work that is taken care of for you in ipython.

Comment: But this code works when you use Spyder, right? Apparently Visual Studio hates interactive mode, but there might be some work around, some discussion here: http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1207

You could always just create lots of figures and then use plt.show() at the end to display them all (assuming that's your goal...).

Comment: @DanHickstein  I don't even expect to see the figure gets updates now. At least it cannot just die like that. *You could always just create lots of figures and then use plt.show() at the end to display them all* this is exactly waht I am trying to do now. But it fails like this: http://i.imgur.com/4o41OBm.png?1

Comment: @tcaswell  it essentially is just the standard REPL without iPython.

Comment: But plotting just one figure works alright? That is weird. I think that actually Visual Studio has iPython. You might be able to switch it somewhere in the options: http://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions/451605